# Convert associative array to numeric array

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I have the following associative array structure in JavaScript

```
Array (
    [-1] => Array (
        catId : -1
        [subCatId] => Array (
             subCatId : -3
            [0] => Array (
                property : value
            )
            [1] => Array (
                property : value
            )
        )
    )
    [-4] => Array (
        catId : -4
        [subCatId] => Array (
             subCatId : -6
            [0] => Array (
                property : value
            )
            [1] => Array (
                property : value
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I want to convert this into numeric Array, like this

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        catID : -1
        [subCatId] => Array (
             subCatId : -3
            [0] => Array (
                property : value
            )
            [1] => Array (
                property : value
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array(
        catID : -4
        [subCatId] => Array (
             subCatId : -3
            [0] => Array (
                property : value
            )
            [1] => Array (
                property : value
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I have tried using,

```
var numeric_array = new Array();
for (var items in Array){
    numeric_array=Array[items];
}
```

but its not achieving my required result, any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this:

```
var numeric_array = new Array();
for (var items in Array){
    numeric_array.push( Array[items] );
}
```

btw, I'm not sure `Array` is good name for you entire array:

```
var hash_array = []; // array which you have
...
var numeric_array = [];
for ( var item in hash_array ){
    numeric_array.push( hash_array[ item ] );
}
```

Comment: Have used Array as a Reference name, my arrayName is different.Thanks for the suggestion, its achieving my required result.